# Issue with react router Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, react-router

I have some issue with using react-router. I get this error and couldn't render my app.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e20Uu.png)

I looking for answer every where but couldn't find anything helpful. So i will be really appreciated if somebody could help me, because I am stuck.

```js
import React from 'react';
import HomePage from './pages/page.create.jsx';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router';
import { createHistory, useBasename } from 'history';

class CreatePage extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='b-container'>
                <div className = 'test'>
                    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
                </div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

//render(<HomePage />, document.body);

const routes = {
    path: '/',
    component: CreatePage,
    childRoutes: [
        { path: 'about', component: HomePage }
    ]
};

render(<Router>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: what does your webpack config look like?

Comment: https://github.com/IlyaLytvynov/notes_manager/blob/master/webpack.config.js - here is a link to webpack config file.

Comment: ya, your config looks fine.  I think @topheman nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass history to your router. Something like that should do the trick:

```
const history = createHistory();
render(<Router history={history}>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. The problem was in react-router version, I tried to use features from v 1.0 but installed was a v13.5. For resolve I reinstall router and everything start fine.